# $4x-1$ is a factor of $p(x)$ which of the following must have a value of 0?

Tags: calculus

Need help with question if $4x-1$ is a factor of $p(x)$ which of the following must have a value of 0? please help

a) $P(-1)$,
b) $P(1)$,
c) $p(1/4)$,
d $p(-1/4)$.

Comment: Hint: Where does $4x - 1 = 0$?

Comment: It states that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a multiple choice question, so you can "cheat." One $p(x)$ which has $4x-1$ as a factor is $4x-1$. Now which of the suggested numbers makes $4x-1$ equal to $0$?
At $x=-1$, $4x-1=-5$; at $x=1$, $4x-1=3$; at $x=\frac{1}{4}$, $4x-1=0$. Got it.

More formally, but you don't need this to answer the question, we have $p(x)=(4x-1)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. Now which of the suggested answers makes $(4x-1)q(x)$ equal to $0$? Since you know nothing about $q(x)$, you focus on the $4x-1$ part. This is $0$ at $x=\frac{1}{4}$. Now you can look at the suggested answers to see whether one of them is $\frac{1}{4}$, maybe in disguised form. Well, there it is at (c), and not even in disguise.

Comment: is the answer b?

Comment: $4*1-1=3$, not $0$, so no, not b.

Comment: @StevenJohn  The answer is 'c' as mentioned in the solution.